# I make a discord bot and it broke

Tags: python

I cannot fix bugs

I tried a method:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

and I expect it to make the bot online but it came out with another error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 21, in <module>
    client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
  File "/home/runner/WhopperBot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 860, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "/nix/store/hd4cc9rh83j291r5539hkf6qd8lgiikb-python3-3.10.8/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/nix/store/hd4cc9rh83j291r5539hkf6qd8lgiikb-python3-3.10.8/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/runner/WhopperBot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 849, in runner
    await self.start(token, reconnect=reconnect)
  File "/home/runner/WhopperBot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 777, in start
    await self.login(token)
  File "/home/runner/WhopperBot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 609, in login
    raise TypeError(f'expected token to be a str, received {token.__class__.__name__} instead')
TypeError: expected token to be a str, received NoneType instead
```

I tried resetting the bot's token but it keeps showing this one.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You haven't actually included the relevant parts of the code.  Do you have ```TOKEN``` environment variable set to your token?

Comment: TOKEN was not found in your environment, so `os.getenv('TOKEN')` returned a null result.  How are you setting TOKEN in the environment?

Comment: See [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). You didn't provide a minimally complete example. You didn't show us that you made even the most minimal effort to research and solve the problem yourself. It would appear that programmer is not the best job for you.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be the token. It says "expected token to be a str, received NoneType instead". Check the following things:

1. Make sure that the variable storing the token is correctly assigned to the value of "TOKEN" environment variable. You're probably messing up in this part... How are you storing the variable?
2. Restart your terminal or IDE: Sometimes you need to restart the IDE, this problem has happened to me before.
3. Check that you're not overwriting the variable TOKEN.

I'd recommend you checking if the variable TOKEN exists at all first

```py
import os

token = os.getenv('TOKEN')

if token is None or not token.strip():
    raise ValueError("Bot token not found :((. (Make sure 'TOKEN' environment variable is set correctly.)")
else:
    print("BOT token found...", token)
```